# What are the prime and maximal ideals of the cartesian product of commutative rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ and $S$ be two commutative rings. Describe the prime and maximal ideals of $R\times S$ in terms of the prime and maximal ideals of $R$ and $S$.

I am asked to solve this question. Under the influence of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170860/maximal-and-prime-ideals-of-cartesian-product-of-rings/1170900?noredirect=1#comment8317862_1170900) and the hint given by Michael Burr I'm now trying to prove that all maximal and prime ideals are of the form $P \times S$ or $R\times P$ or $M\times S$ or $R\times M$ for $P,M$ a prime and maximal ideal respectively. *I was wondering if my ideas are correct, or if there were any holes in my proof ?* ._.

I am able to deduce that all ideals of $R\times S$ must be of the form $I\times J$ for $I,J$ ideals of $R$ and $S$ respectively, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101214/structure-of-ideals-in-the-product-of-two-rings). (If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J$ is an ideal of $S$ then $I\times J$ is an ideal of $R\times S$, and if $I$ is an ideal of $R\times S$ then there are ideals of $R$ and $S$ such that $I=I_R \times I_S$).

From Corollary 14 of chapter 7 of Dummit and Foote:

> Assume $R$ is commutative. Every maximal ideal of $R$ is a prime ideal.

As mentioned in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170860/maximal-and-prime-ideals-of-cartesian-product-of-rings/1170900?noredirect=1#comment8317862_1170900) if $P_1,P_2$ are proper prime ideals, then $P_1 \times P_2$ cannot be a prime ideal because given $r \not\in P_1$ and $s \not \in P_2$ then $(r,0)\times(0,s) = (0,0) \in P_1\times P_2$ but $(r,0),(0,s) \not\in P_1 \times P_2$. Since maximal ideals are prime ideals, given $M_1, M_2$ maximal/prime proper ideals, then $M_1 \times M_2$ is not prime, and thus not maximal. A two for one...

If the above is correct, both ideals cannot be proper, thus only one ideal must be the whole ring $R$ or $S$, $R\times S$ would not be proper and prime and maximal ideals are proper ideals. (All prime and maximal ideals must be of the form $P \times S$ or $R\times P$ or $M\times S$ or $R\times M$).

Following through to the next step in the hint I try taking quotients (to show that they are actually maximal or prime ideals):

$P \times S$ or $R\times P$ must be prime ideals for $P$ a prime ideal:

${R\times S}/{R\times P} = \{(r,s)+R\times P | r\in R \text{ and } s\in S\}$

If $s \in P$ then $(r,s) + R\times P = 0 + R\times P$

suppose $(r,s),(r',s')\not\in R\times P$ and $[(r,s)+R\times P]\times [(r',s')+ R\times P] = (r\cdot r', s\cdot s') + R\times P = 0 + R\times P$

then $s,s' \not\in P$ and $s\cdot s' \in P$, but $P$ is prime, contradiction. ${R\times S}/{R\times P}$ has no zero divisors. I guess that makes ${R\times S}/{R\times P}$ into an integral domain if it is assumed that $R,S$ have identity $1\not= 0$... thus $R\times P$ is a prime ideal, similarly $P\times S$ is prime.

I'm not so sure about a two for one in this case,

**Is there a way to show that $R\times S / M\times S$ or $R\times S / R\times M$ is a field?**

I think the latter would be maximal by a direct proof?

Suppose there is an ideal $M\times S \subset I \subset R$ then $I$ must be of the form $J\times S$ for some ideal $J$ of $R$ where $M \subset J \subset R$. Contradiction because $M$ is maximal. Thus $M\times S$ is maximal in $R\times S$ and similarly $R\times M$ is maximal in $R\times S$. Does this work?

Comment: Are your initial rings just commutative or domains?  The answer depends on the initial rings.

Comment: pretty sure just commutative, that's all I got for the question

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening in the line that begins, "Suppose that $(r, s), (r', s') \notin R \times P.$" In particular, how do you should that the product is zero in the line that immediately follows?

Comment: @Carlo I took (r,s),(r′,s′)∉R×P because in the definition given in Dummit & Foote, a zero divisor must be nonzero and an element of R×S/R×P is zero if (r,s)∈R×P thus if you had two nonzero elements in R×S/R×P such that when multiplied gave you zero in R×S/R×P is the same as being an element of R×P ‍♂️ that's all I got...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $I \subset R$ and $J \subset S$ are left ideals of rings $R$ and $S$, then the product of the quotient maps

$$
p_I \times p_J \colon R \times S \to R/I \times S/J
$$

has in its kernel the precisely the elements $(x,y)$ such that $x \in I, y \in J$. By the first isomorphism theorem, we get

$$
\frac{R \times S}{I \times J} \simeq R/I \times S/J.\tag{1}
$$

Now, a product $A \times B$ of two non-zero rings $A$ and $B$ aways has zero divisors: taking $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ both non-zero, we get $(0,0) = (a,0)(0,b)$.

Hence if $I \times J$ is prime (resp. maximal), one of the factors in the right hand side of $(1)$ must be trivial, and the other must be a domain (resp. field). This translates to saying that one of the ideals must be the whole ring and the other prime (resp. maximal).