# Finding the Ideals of a Direct Product of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R_1 = \mathbb{Z}$, and $R_2 = \mathbb{F}_4$. Find all ideals in $R_1\times R_2$. Which of them are principal ideals? Which are prime? Which are maximal?

I know the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$, but I am having trouble finding the ideals in the cartesian product of both of these rings.  If someone could help me out it would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be useful:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734476/ideals-in-direct-product-of-rings

Answer (score 2):

For two *unitary* rings $A,B$ one has that every ideal $I$ of $A\times B$ is actually equal to $J_A\times J_B$, for some ideal $J_A,J_B$ in the respective rings (see [Structure of ideals in the product of two rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101214/structure-of-ideals-in-the-product-of-two-rings)).

This is the case in your example, so all you need to know is what the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$ are (and then study their properties - maximality, primality, principality).